# InflateException in custom list view

Tags: android, listview

i get the following error when run the application

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

line 33 in layout file

```
<view
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/value1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBorder" ></view>
```

Comment: `View` . Not `view`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V in view should be capital

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/value1dp"
    android:background="@color/colorBorder" ></View>
```

Comment: Indeed indeed .

Answer (score 0):

It's `View`, not `view`:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/value1dp"
    android:background="@color/colorBorder" ></View>
```